# how to mock spring context file

Tags: java

I am writing the Junit for Spring appication, I have class `Abc` annotated with `@Component` and contains `@Value` annotation for fetching variable values from property file.

When I am doing below to run Junit Test case:

```
Abc abc = new Abc();

String result = abc.getDataElement();

assertEquals("helloWorldHere",result);
```

I am getting error as (expexted is helloWorldHere but actual is hellonullHere )

I am getting `null` for the property value variable.
How should I write Junit so that I can use the value of property file as well
and if creating object with new keyword in Spring is not right then how to mock the Spring context file to create object for this class `ABC`.

Comment: Please improve formatting in your question

Comment: You should be mocking the property file using some Mock framework such as [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to constructor injection and pass dataElement as constructor parameter.